# Show message on products (view.phtml) within specified category only

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes, product-attribute, product-view

I have a message "Call for Best Price" on my Magento store if a product has the attribute `priceless` set to **yes**.

Currently this is applied to all products as **yes**. I'd like for it to show only on products in a **specified category** (e.g. Shoes [ID:10]).

**My current code in `catalog/product/view.phtml` is as follows**

```
<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('priceless') == $this->__('Yes')): ?>
 <p>Please call for best price</p>
<?php endif; // PriceLess Product ?>
```

Can anyone suggest an edit to get this working for only the specified category (ID: 10)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is too easy you **need to get categories ids from product and Current category id** then check your *category is exit in this list*

```
<?php
/* get product categories ids */
$CategoryIds = array();
$CategoryIds =$_product->getCategoryIds();
if(Mage::registry('current_category')):
    $CategoryIds[] = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
endif;
$checkCategory = 10;
if($_product->getAttributeText('priceless') == $this->__('Yes') 
    && in_array($checkCategory , $CategoryIds )
): ?>
<p>Please call for best price</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: And if there were multiple values Amit, presumably '= array (10,11,12);' minus the quotes.

Comment: it so simple, just use a loop

Answer (score 1):

Magento product can be assigned to multiple categories. So you need to get all categories id and check.

```
    $productObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_product->getId());
    $categoryIds = $productObj->getCategoryIds();
    if(in_array(10, $categoryIds)) {
        // your code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ids = $_product->getCategoryId();
$configId = 10; //You can make it dynamic by set it in Custom Configuration.

<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('priceless') == $this->__('Yes')): 
 if (in_array($configId , $ids )) { ?>

 <p>Please call for best price</p>

 <?php }
 endif; // PriceLess Product 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the category is an anchor category, it is not enough to check if the id (10) is assigned to the product, you also have to check if a child category is assigned to the product.

But we do not need to do this manually, we can use the product collection which will determine which products belong to the category based on anchor settings:

```
$shoeCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(10);

$productCollection = $shoeCategory->getProductCollection()
    ->addIdFilter($_product->getId());

if ($productCollection->getSize() === 1) {
    ?> Please call for best price <?php
}
```

By using `getSize()` the collection is not loaded but only a single `SELECT COUNT`  query is executed.

---

On an unrelated note: the following line is unnecessarily complicated and error-prone:

```
<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('priceless') == $this->__('Yes')): ?>
```

Compare the internal value instead:

```
<?php if($_product->getData('priceless')): ?>
```

I assume that "priceless" has the source model `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean`, which has the values 0 and 1 for "yes" and "no". If not, I recommend to change it, it's not too late as long as all values are "yes".

Comment: Priceless is 'yes' or 'no' text based on dropdown options chosen by the user. Presume getData would not work in this case?

Comment: It does. Look how the value is stored internally

Comment: I see - not all values in the category will be 'yes'.